# Strange definition of a two-level system by the Bloch vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, definition, density-operator, bloch-sphere

A two-level system can be described by a density operator involving the [Bloch vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere)

$$
\vec{r}; \quad r_x = Tr(\rho X); \quad r_y = Tr(\rho Y); \quad r_z = Tr(\rho Z)
$$

as

$$
\rho = \frac{I + \vec{r}\cdot \vec{\sigma}}{2}
$$

where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are the Pauli operators.

What is the physical idea behind defining the density operator for a two-level system like this, and in particular what is $\vec{\sigma}$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density operator combines *pure* quantum states into a *mixed* quantum state. The basic idea is to take a system composed of many pure states and to represent them as a single object, which evolves in time, as a complete system.

In this example, the mixed state is represented as a Block sphere, and the $\vec{\sigma}$ is a [pauli matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). The Bloch sphere is essentially a representation of the system that can be thought of as a sphere with basis vectors X, Y, Z in your case, which each represent the pure states. The Bloch vector points somewhere in the sphere, pointing to a mixed state (which, if it were pointing only along X, would be a pure state)